# How to write a Custom Input Format

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am a newbie to **Hadoop** and I have a situation where only one line per 4 lines of the input text is relevant. Currently I am using the default `TextInputFormat` and a conditional logic to skip all the other three lines which is irrelevant.

How can I use a `Custom Input Format` to handle this. Since Am new to hadoop I don't know much about `CustomInputFormat`. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `NLineInputFormat` where you can specify how many line constructs one record. This could be easy & ready to use solution.

If you want to implement your own input format then it you would probably implement custom input format & record reader to specify what constructs your one record.

below is one of of the example 
http://deep-developers.blogspot.in/2014/06/custom-input-split-and-custom.html

Comment: Thanks for the response ! How to use the NLineInputFormat and how to specify the lines to read in it ?

Comment: in Driver you can set `setInputFormat` as `NLineInputFormat` and for customizing you will need to set property `mapre duce.input.lineinputformat.linespermap` or old api `mapred.line.input.format.linespermap`